# Visual Studio c# relative path, program searching two paths even when it finds the correct one

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, path, visual-studio-2017

I'm developing a desktop application for windows using visual studio. I'm programming in C# using WPF for UI.

I've googled looking for an answer, but haven't found any. Most likely because I don't exactly know what the actual problem is.

I've run into a problem where I'm trying to access a file in the folder resources
(C:\Users\MyName\Projects\MyProject\ProjectName\resources\xml\test.xml)
Using this code:

```
XElement xmlFromFile = XElement.Load(@"..\..\resources\xml\test.xml");
```

The issue is that the file is found and the xml can be accessed through the xmlFromFile variable, BUT the program also searches

```
D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\resources\xml\test.xml
```

The same also happens if I try this:

```
static string codePath = Directory.GetParent(Directory.GetParent(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location)).FullName).FullName;
FileLog log = new FileLog(codePath + "\\logs\\log.txt");
log.Log("Test")
```

Where codePath refers to the directory where the class files are, FileLog is a class that simply logs to a file using File.AppendAllText(path, string).
This piece of code gives the same error, but the path is instead:

```
C:\Users\MyName\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\15.0_919b9cb1\Designer\ShadowCache\logs\log.txt
```

But this one also writes the input string(test) to the correct file in the correct place. So why is this a problem if it works? While it works correctly here, the issue is that WPF does not give me a preview of the UI like it usually does, there's probably also other issues, but none that I am aware of. The preview simply states: Cannot create an instance of "Home". Where Home is a WPF UserControl.

So my question is: How to I fix the code so that the program does not search in both places(if indeed that's what it does)?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is happening here I believe is not that the program is not searching multiple places for a file, but the assembly from which the relative file search is being done is being loaded from different places.  .NET has a fascinating and little understood mechanism for finding an assembly and loading it which is described in this document: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682586(v=vs.85).aspx

So I think what is happening is that you are examining this behavior in different contexts (i.e. using the debugger, in the designer, etc.) and the assembly that is being used is loaded from a different place and therefore evaluates the relative file path differently.

So if I am right, then you are chasing a shadow.  This is an artifact of behavior on your development machine which will disappear once the application is deployed and there is only one place for .NET to find the release assembly.

Comment: Thank you for a quick answer. I'm glad to hear it shouldn't have any other side-effects. Do you know of any way to make WPF show the preview even when the error is there? It's not crucial, I could just run the application, but it would be handy.